# Update json column's individual values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have a user structure like so:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->text('phone');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('postal');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('google2fa_secret');
        $table->text('balance');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now, I am storing values in the 'balance' column like so

```
{
    "usd": 10,
    "gbp": 10,
    "eur": 10
}
```

How can I edit for example `usd` value but keep the others in the array with attributes?

How I am getting the attributes:

```
/**
 * Get the user's balance
 *
 * @return decimal
 */
public function getBalanceAttribute()
{
    return json_decode( $this->attributes['balance'] );
}
```

Comment: why you are having `$table->text('balance');` as in laravel they have `$table->json('options');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose in your users you want to fetch by id and then update then you can do something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['balance->usd' => 12]);
```

But make sure that is an `json` column I mean you need to define `$table->json('balance');` in your migration. Then you won't be requiring accessor to get `json_encode` attribute.

For more information check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updating-json-columns) part.

Comment: unfortunatly, my database does not support json tables, thus not allowing this code to work